# How to check for null before comparing by linked object key using Comparator.comparing in java

Tags: java-8, comparator

```
Comparator.comparing(ProjectVo::getCategory, Comparator.comparing(ProjectCategoryVo::getName))
```

However category can be null and hence this is throwing exception when sorted

How can i apply null comparator for category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use naturalOrder to guard against getCategory returning null:

```java
Comparator.comparing(ProjectVo::getCategory,
    Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(ProjectCategoryVo::getName)));
```

If I was worried about getName returning null I would use that trick:

```java
Comparator.comparing(ProjectVo::getCategory,
    Comparator.comparing(ProjectCategoryVo::getName,
        Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

If I was worried about a ProjectVo being null:

```java
Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(ProjectVo::getCategory,
        Comparator.comparing(ProjectCategoryVo::getName)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I achieved it using Comparator.comparing((ProjectVo pvo) -> {
    return pvo.getCategory() == null ? "" : pvo.getCategory().getName();
   }); Do you see any issue in this?

Comment: @Shiv that would consider empty strings and `null` as equal and produce an unpredictable order for them. The other issue is that there is no reason for such a manual handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`nullsFirst`** or **`nullsLast`** methods available in `java.util.Comparator` in order to handle the null value during the comparison.

***1. Using `nullsFirst` method***

```
Comparator.comparing(ProjectVo::getCategory, 
                     Comparator.comparing(ProjectCategoryVo::getName),
                     Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

***2. Using `nullsLast` method***

```
Comparator.comparing(ProjectVo::getCategory, 
                     Comparator.comparing(ProjectCategoryVo::getName),
                     Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

> You can use `Comparator.naturalOrder()` or `Comparator.reverseOrder()`
> with `nullsFirst` and `nullsLast` methods based on your type of
> sorting.